# Chromium localStorage not showing in Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, local-storage, chromium, web-developer-toolbar

Trying to view my test `localStorage`, I see nothing in the Storage section under Applications in the Developer Tools.
However, using the console, I can access it, meaning its clearly there.
Am I missing something or does this seem to be a bug I couldn't find anything about?

[image]

I am using Chromium Version 57.0.2978.0 (64-bit)

Comment: Same issue here. Key/value pair is blatantly there (can be accessed programatically), but not to be seen in the dev tools. I am working locally, but using a server.

Comment: If you refresh the page while DevTools is open, it ceases to display the data any longer :(.

I've had to:
1. Close DevTools
2. Refresh the page
3. Reopen DevTools... and the data is displayed once again.

Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)  MacOS

Comment: Even after 5 years, I am also facing the same issue in Version 109.0.5414.120 (Official Build) (64-bit). Reported to the google community as well.

Answer (score 27):

[Its a known Bug (#701413)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=701413)

[They fixed it in version 59.0.3069.0 (#718482)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=718482)

I can see the localStorage of different domains like FB, but not from the current domain. When starting up developer tools it appears, but disappears after a reload.

Comment: Until they fix the issue, following extension is a nice replacement. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html5-storage-manager-all/giompennnhheakjcnobejbnjgbbkmdnd?hl=en

Answer (score 15):

Workaround: re-open the Dev Tool, that is press F12 twice. Tested on Ubuntu Chrome 58.

Comment: This worked for me on version 109.0.5414.119

Answer (score 13):

I have been encountering the same issue. Not a great solution, but if one closes the developer tools and reopens the developer tools, one will find the domain showing again under Local Storage with all the local storage name value pairs. At least I found a nice shortcut to open and close the developer tools researching this issue. cmd + option + i for mac. I hope this helps my fellow coders. Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) MacOS.

Comment: Same problem here on Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) Mac. Close and re-open dev tools and it shows again.

Comment: I am doing some tests with localStorage and Auth0 and I found it really annoying that it wasn't showing in the developer console, now it's easy enough just to reopen the console again... Hope they come up with a fix though

Comment: Has anyone encountered or implemented Truste on a site when this localStorage issue started? Thanks.

Comment: In windows: ctrl + shift + i

Comment: Only when I chose console tab before close/open did it work. (on windows)

Answer (score 7):

The workaround described in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=701413#c59 worked for me:

> If the active tab when opening DevTools is 'Application', then it always fails. However, if the active tab is any of the other tabs, then it actually works as expected and loads Local Storage values. So my solution is to select 'Console' tab, then close and reopen DevTools, and it works.

Comment: As of 03/01/2023 this is *still* a live pestering bug in Chrome DevTools, and the above is the only hack to avoid the bug.

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered the same issue on my MAC. Open settings in dev tools and **restore to the default view**.

Comment: "Restore defaults and reload" in dev tools settings was the only thing that worked for me.