# Ghost bug in chrome browser with local-storage

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage

I've found an interesting case. 
There is a react app which uses local-storage. So we login and got the token saved in it. But when we reload the page, it's not there. Moreover, if we try to type: 

`localStorage.setItem("hello", "world")`
 
It will not work. Local-storage gonna be totally empty whatever we do. 
And it will be the same after hard reload. I can't put there any value.

Only after closing the whole browser it will be able to work with local-storage for selected tab.

So in common the problem happens only after reload the page. 
I've no idea what it could be! That's the most weird bug I've ever seen.

Comment: Version number? I couldn't duplicate this with Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) on a Mac. I just used your code here on this page and the `hello: "world"` is still there after I reload.

Comment: That's correct. We had issue with our app only. 
So that's why I'm trying to find someone who had similar problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chromium localStorage not showing in Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703129/chromium-localstorage-not-showing-in-developer-tools)